# read 2d grey images and combine them to 3d matrix

Tags: matlab

I have some problems with matlab 2015a Win10 X64 16GB Ram.

There is a bunch of images (1280x960x8bit) and I want to load them into a 3d matrix. In theory that matrix should store ~1.2GB for 1001 images.

What I have so far is:

```
values(:,:,:)= zeros(960, 1280, 1001, 'uint8');
for i = Start:Steps:End
    file = strcat(folderStr, filenameStr, num2str(i), '.png');
    img = imread(file);
    values(:,:,i-Start+1) = img;
end
```

This code is working for small amount of images but using it for all 1001 images I get "Out of memory" error.
Another problem is the speed.
Reading 50 images and save them takes me ~2s, reading 100 images takes ~48s.

What I thought this method does is allocating the memory and change the "z-elements" of the matrix picture by picture. But obviously it holds more memory than needed to perform that single task.

Is there any method I can store the grey values of a 2d picture sequence to a 3d matrix in matlab without wasting that much time and ressources?

Thank you

Comment: you can [Download more RAM](http://downloadmoreram.com/) . In am ore serious note, you can not create a single variable that contains all that information if your computer RAM can not store that information.....  What are you supposed to do with it? If its a single variable, then anything that involves it will require the whole variable loaded, and it doesnt fit in your memory!! However, check the variable type.  is img `double` or `uint8`? What is its range?

Comment: To add about what I said. If you load them as `uint8(imread(file))`, do you still get the error?

Comment: resolution 1280x960x8bit depthx1001 pictures = 1174MB with more than 14GB of free Ram that should not be the problem!

No uint8(..) is not working

The picture is 8bit color depth.

Comment: is the picture 8bit color depth in memory also? When you type `whos img` doest it tells you that is Class `uint8` ? Also, why dont you iterate as 
`i=1:steps:1001` ? If in your code the for loop variables are not set up, then the values would grow a lot. You can also just remove `(:,:,:)` from the definition of `values`

Comment: The picture is 8 bit color depth (also in whos img).
I do not use i=1:steps:1001 because the name of the images ist not 1,2,3,4,... because of they are named after a position from the sensor.
There must be another problem as i said initially reading 50 images is working good and fast enough but it uses exponentially more ram and time with increasing amount of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility I can see is that your idexes are bad. But I can only guess because the values of start step and End are not given. If End is 100000000, Start is 1 and step is 100000000, you are only reading 2 images, but you are accessing values(:,:,100000000) thus making the variable incredibly huge. That is, most likely, your problem.

To solve this, create a new variable:

```
imagenames=Start:Step:End; %note that using End as a variable sucks, better ending
for ii=1:numel(imagenames);
    file = strcat(folderStr, filenameStr, num2str(imagenames(ii)), '.png');
    img = imread(file);
    values(:,:,ii) = img;
end
```

As Shai suggests, have a look to `fullfile` for better filename accessing

Comment: it is better to use `fullfile` instead of `strcat` for filenames and paths.

Comment: Indeed @Shai ! I didnt even look at that, just triying to fix the other things!

Comment: The numbers are originally named different and the values are:
piezoStart = 43000;
piezoEnd = 63000;
piezoSteps = 20;

Comment: @akirahinoshiro so I am rigth. The last iteration of your loop will have `values(:,:,20001)` And that is a HUGE matrix, 20 times bigger than the one you are trying to make.